# excel vba sorting currency column descending

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with 2 columns A has shopnames and B has currency values

I want to sort in descending order column B

Here's what I have done:

```
With Sheets("helpsheet")
    .Sort Key1:=Range("A"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes       
End With
```

It doesn't work. What do I have to do differently?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? We can't see your screen or read your mind from here. Please [edit] your question and be specific about what the problem is you're asking us to help you solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options of sorting available in VBA. The simplest way to improve you code is to add a range of data which you want to sort. Therefore you need to improve your code to the following:

```
With Sheets("helpsheet").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

What I did:

1. assumed that your data range starts in `Range("A1")` and makes a region (therefore I used `CurrentRegion property` in `With` line.
2. I set sorting key to `Range("B1")` according to information from your question.

If required you could change these points accordingly to your situation.